# getting problem in installation of flutter in PC

Tags: flutter

I have installed all the necessary tools but still, it's showing the error. I have installed all the required SDK files twice three times but still, it is showing the error.

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvXch.jpg)

Comment: run this command in the same terminal you posted in the picture: flutter doctor --android-licenses

Comment: Already answered:
[here :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60475481/flutter-doctor-error-android-sdkmanager-tool-not-found-windows) you are just missing a little part

Answer (score 0):

In terminal run

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

it will display y/no enter y and hit enter again till you accept all licences.

Comment: it shows this. My all SDK files are already installed but still, it shows like this.   [   Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmd line tools are installed to
resolve this. ]