# Android sdkmanager not found. still appears, although, Android SDK Command-line tools is already installed

Tags: android, flutter

I'm having this problem trying to install flutter: "Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to
resolve this.", this happends when I try to run "flutter doctor --android-licenses".

[image: Here is the error].

I've already tried this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60475481/flutter-doctor-error-android-sdkmanager-tool-not-found-windows).
I also installed the "Android SDK Tools(Obsolete)", and didn't work.

Here is a picture of my SDK Tools in Android Studio.

[image: Here]

The last thing I tried is this installing from CMD

[image: here]

Here is an image of mi enviroment variables:

Flutter:

[image]

JAVA_HOME:

[image]

And also put this inside the System variables path:

[image]

[image]

But, still gives me the same error.

What can I do to solve this, I've been stuck here two days now.

Answer (score 0):

you have to have the path of Flutter Bin  inside " C " not anywhere else.
this is my path.
"C/src/flutter/flutter/bin".

then try flutter doctor inside "flutter.console "

Comment: That did not work, I put it in "C:\flutter\flutter_windows_3.3.8-stable\flutter\bin", but the result was the same