# vs code: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: java, flutter, visual-studio-code

in my vs code i'm building an app in flutter language and it worked perfect without errors but suddenly it   stopped running ( i tried to upgrade flutter sdk but nothing changed) i can't figure out if the problem from java rmi or kotlin
please check the error in terminal below and help me to solve this out :

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:623)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:132)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:235)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:180)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.compile(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.incrementalCompilationWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:289)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compileWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:217)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compileWithDaemonOrFallback(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:166)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compileWithDaemonOrFallback(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:63)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.KotlinCompilerRunner.runCompiler(KotlinCompilerRunner.kt:133)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runJvmCompiler(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:119)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:393)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:297)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:259)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:452)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:262)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.LoopbackNetworkInterface$ClientLoopbackSocketFactory.createSocket(NetworkUtils.kt:86)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:617)
        ... 65 more
warning: the '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-Xbuild-file' is specified
Note: C:\Users\saad\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.9.1+hotfix.6-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-2.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
e: C:\Users\saad\Desktop\PauseApp\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\retroportalstudio\www\foodies_app\MainActivity.kt: (11, 44): Type mismatch: inferred type is MainActivity but FlutterEngine was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details




check my code below:





    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    // import 'package:foodies_app/breakfast.dart';
    import 'package:material_design_icons_flutter/material_design_icons_flutter.dart';
    // import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
    import 'package:footer/footer.dart';
    import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
    // import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
    import 'package:footer/footer_view.dart';
    import 'package:localize_and_translate/localize_and_translate.dart';

    // void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

      await translator.init(
        localeType: LocalizationDefaultType.device,
        languagesList: <String>['ar', 'en'],
        assetsDirectory: 'assets/langs/',
        // apiKeyGoogle: '<Key>', // NOT YET TESTED
      ); // intialize

      runApp(LocalizedApp(child: MyApp()));
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Home(),
          localizationsDelegates: translator.delegates, // Android + iOS Delegates
          locale: translator.locale, // Active locale
          supportedLocales: translator.locals(),
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(),
        );
      }
    }

    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
    }

    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
      // VideoPlayerController _controller;
      @override
      @override
      @override
      // void initState() {
      //   super.initState();
      //   // Pointing the video controller to our local asset.
      //   _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/02.mp4")
      //     ..initialize().then((_) {
      //       // Once the video has been loaded we play the video and set looping to true.
      //       _controller.play();
      //       _controller.setLooping(true);
      //       // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized.
      //       setState(() {});
      //     });
      //   @override
      //   void dispose() {
      //     super.dispose();
      //     _controller.dispose();
      //   }
      // }

      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return


            Scaffold(
                // TODO 6: Create a Stack Widget
                body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          // TODO 7: Add a SizedBox to contain our video.
          SizedBox.expand(
            child: FittedBox(
              // If your background video doesn't look right, try changing the BoxFit property.
              // BoxFit.fill created the look I was going for.
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              // child: SizedBox(
              //   width: _controller.value.size?.width ?? 0,
              //   height: _controller.value.size?.height ?? 0,
              //   child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              // ),
            ),
          ),
        ]));
      }
    }
```

is there a way to solve it?
thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any errors while running `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\saad\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.  @YeasinSheikh

Comment: You can follow those official docs links also you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49068629/10157127) , hope it will solve the issue